# IS there any Tool or API to auto update a database structure

Tags: database, delphi, database-versioning, blackfish

In an application that I am supporting, lately I have made several changes to the DB structure.

I send the update to the users, but its very hard to keep them all up-to-date.

Is there any simple way to do this ?

Something that enables users to skip versions, but still do the update in the next version they install.

I use BlackFish database.

Thanks

Comment: Ensure that the patches are applied in the correct order? You shouldn't have any problems at all then.

Comment: Agree with @Ben, if your user skip some of the updates, once he perform it, install all previous updates in a sequence before you apply the latest one. It's IMHO the most painless way to do so.

Comment: I didn't know anybody actually used BlackFish SQL.

Comment: Now you know ... I use it for small projects, with few users. It's nice, good performance, easy to install.
I am switching to FireBird late this year, but till then I need to simplify database versioning.

Answer (score 5):

Just store database version number in the database and write migration scripts like this:

- database_10.sql - initial db structure
- database_10_15.sql - migration script to move from 1.0 to 1.5
- database_10_17.sql - migration script to move from 1.5 to 1.7

Check database version number on every application startup and apply needed migration scripts.

Answer (score 0):

**Side note:**

Another appealing alternative to it also for small project is Component ACE [Absolute Database](http://www.componentace.com/bde_replacement_database_delphi_absolute_database.htm).

---

**Now direct to the point:**

The personnal edition (Free) comes with a custom utility named *DBManager* (along with its source code).

[image]

It can serve as starting point to how to manage database structure change programmatically (the Delphi way!).

Why not port it to BlackFish?

Answer (score 0):

I very rarely change Databases but just add a table or sometimes a colunm. When I startup my program it checks for the existance of said column or table and if it's not there it just tries to make it.